# How WhatsApp knows that account is logged in on 1 device

Tags: authentication, whatsapp

Recently I was switching devices and my WhatsApp got logged out from 1st device when I logged in to 2nd device.
And I got this question on my mind
How WhatsApp knows that account is logged in on 1 device only

Answer (score 1):

When you login to WhatsApp on a new device, WhatsApp sends a login request to its servers, along with a unique code that is generated on your new device. If the servers find that you are already logged in on another device, they will automatically log you out of the other device, in order to protect the security of your account. This is why you were logged out of your first device when you logged in to your second device.

WhatsApp uses this system to ensure that your account can only be accessed from one device at a time, which helps to protect your account from unauthorized access. If you need to use WhatsApp on more than one device, you can use the "WhatsApp Web" feature, which allows you to access your WhatsApp account from a web browser on your computer.

Comment: The "secret code" that you are referring to is likely the encryption key that WhatsApp uses to secure your messages. This key is stored on your device and is used to encrypt and decrypt the messages that you send and receive through the app. It is not possible for you to access or retrieve this key directly, as it is stored in an encrypted format for security purposes.